# jQuery: How to show an element and use the highlight effect at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I have two elements on a page.

```
<div id="a">content</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none">different content</div>
```

When I click the currently displayed `div`, I want to hide it and show the other one. This is easy to do:

```
$('#a').hide();
$('#b').show();
```

But now I want to take it a step further and highlight the element as it is being displayed. I think that it will involve `effect("highlight")`, but I can't get it to work. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing is to correct your ID attributes. They are not allowed to start with a number.

Given that, you probably just need to load jQueryUI. It is required for that effect to work.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/r6pKn/

HTML

```
<div id="div1">content</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">different content</div>​
```

jQuery

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $('#div2').show().effect('highlight');
});​
```

Comment: sorry, i just used 1 and 2 for example purposes, but you are right, you can't have ids that start with a number

Comment: no, not yet. can't get it to work. I just added jquery-ui-1.7.3

Comment: @Andrew - What version of jQuery are you using? And what does your actual code look like? You can edit your question if needed.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2. That's why I chose jQuery UI 1.7.3. My code looks exactly the same. Your jsfiddle example is working, so it must be right. I've decided to move on since I can't figure out how what's wrong in my environment.

Comment: @Andrew - Alright. Only other thing I'd suggest is to make sure you have the javascript loaded in the proper order. jQuery, then jQueryUI, then your javascript. Best of luck. :o)