# how to show the dynamically added UL Li element highlighted for 3-5 seconds after click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am adding the UL,LI elements dynamically on click of button.now once they are added i have to show them as highlighted on UI for some time like 3-6 seconds.

Comment: You can use  jQueryUI. [How to show an element and use the highlight effect at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311965/jquery-how-to-show-an-element-and-use-the-highlight-effect-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/f8e2Y/3/

```
$('button').click(function(){
 $('div').append('<ul><li>Content1</li><li>Content2</li></ul>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div ul:last').css('background-color','#CCC');
    },100);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('ul').css('background-color','#FFF');
    },5000);
});
```